# Multidimensional array splice

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay this is probaly an easy fix, but I'm having a bad time trying to get this to work.
Anyway I have an array $tableData which output is:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => content1 [1] => content1) 
[2] => Array( [0] => content2 [1] => content2) 
[3] => Array (.... etc etc etc
```

I want to remove the array[0] because it's always empty
thing's i've tried:

```
$tableData=array_shift($tableData);
```

Which gives output:

```
Array ( )
```

Also I've tried

```
$tableData=array_splice($tableData, 0, 1);
```

Which gives output

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

Wanted output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => content1 [1] => content1) 
[2] => Array( [0] => content2 [1] => content2) 
[3] => Array (.... etc etc etc
```

Help much appreciated! :)

Answers from below fixed it, thought you had to reassign the variable but you should not in my case.
Changed

```
$tableData=array_shift($tableData);
```

to

```
array_shift($tableData);
```

Comment: why do you want to remove array index 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_shift($tableData);
```

`array_shift` *returns* the shifted element. If you overwrite your `$tableData` variable with that element, that's what you get. Just shift the array without reassigning it, done.

Answer (score 3):

If you assign a variable to array shift, it will populate with the value that was removed.

If you just do

```
array_shift($tableData);
```

Then the first key and value for `$tableData` should be removed.